# Permanent and SE-wide solutions to "Retry Using Another Source"?

Tags: support

I often encounter the following problem

[image]

The link under "Retry Using Another Source" is https://unix.stackexchange.com/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie.
That solves the problem.

But

- after a few days without visiting the website, I encounter the same problem again.
- The setting isn't set for all the sites of StackExchange

Are there solutions to the above two problems?